# How to retrieve values from the URL in Go?

Tags: database, go, url

For example if the website is [https://www.example.com/signup?campaign='new_york'](https://www.example.com/signup?campaign=%27new_york%27), I would like to strip out the value of campaign, 'new_york'. Thanks!

Comment: Use `req.FormValue("campaign")`

Answer (score 5):

You should find the query parameters by using this

```
campaign := r.URL.Query().Get("campaign")
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got too many layers of indirection to determine the issue. Either use a debugger or logging to determine if the value you get back from `r.URL.Query().Get()` is what you expect, in order to determine where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the query string value by this code:

```
http.HandleFunc("/signup", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    q := r.URL.Query()
    campaign := q.Get("campaign")
    fmt.Println("campaign =>", campaign)
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```